# Trying to create a score balk with php

Tags: php, html, css

```
<li class="menu pbar">Rank: <?php echo createBalk($rank['procenten']); ?></li>
<li class="menu pbar">leven: <?php echo createBalk($leven); ?></li>
```

```
function createBalk($score) {

    if($score >= 100) {
        return "<div class='progress-bar'>
            <div class='pfull' width='$score'>{$score}%</div>
        </div>";
    } elseif($score >= 50 && $score < 100) {
        return "<div class='progress-bar'>
            <div class='pfull' width='$score'>{$score}%</div>
            <div class='pempty' width='100 - $score'></div>
        </div>";
    } elseif($score < 50 && $score > 0) {
        return "";
    } elseif($score == 0) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

```
.pbar {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar {
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.pfull {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height: 100%; 
}

.pempty {
    background-color: #008000;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If i try make a balk for my website but somehow the balk never show up in the right way. From the function createBalk.

Lets say $score is 60. then balk must be 60 light green 40 dark green. This normally gives me a balk off 100% width.

Somehow that doesnt happen if i dont give it any text it wont show up at all.
For some reason the div width doesnt work.

Can someone help me thx for having look/crack at it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

100 - $score won’t work. Try instead:

```
“ . (100 - $score) . “%
```

Also add the % in the pfull div.
Here the two lines to change:

```
<div class='pfull' width='$score%'>{$score}%</div>
<div class='pempty' width='”. (100 - $score) . “%'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out whats wrong.
here new code that works the way it suppose to be.

```
function createBalk($score) {

$minscore = 100 - $score;

if($score >= 100) {
    return "<div class='progress-bar'>
        <div class='pfull' style='width:$score%;'>{$score}%</div>
    </div>";
} elseif($score >= 50 && $score < 100) {
    return "<div class='progress-bar'>
        <div class='pfull' style='width:$score%;'></div>
        <div class='pempty' style='width:$minscore%;'></div>
    </div>";
} elseif($score < 50 && $score > 0) {
    return "";
} elseif($score == 0) {
    return "";
}
```

}